# str_replace Ð to &

Tags: php, replace

I want to replace the char Ð into &.

im trying the following simple str_replace

```
str_replace("Ð","&",$string)
```

but somehow is not working..

Answer (score 5):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) returns its result, it doesn't change its argument.

```
$string = str_replace("Ð","&",$string);
```

Comment: the problem is my parsing the Ð through GET. example: www.x.com/sÐe.html which is artist.php?name=sÐe

Comment: @Peibol It looks like your problem is completely unrelated to replacing then. Better open a new question.

Comment: Is str_replace even utf8 safe?  I'm not finding on .net about an mbstring equivalent, so I wonder if it might be or not...

Comment: @Obsidian_ `str_replace` is binary-safe (and therefore, if you use UTF-8, UTF-8-safe). See the linked documentation for details

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a problem with charsets.. a workaround could be use htmlentities() on the string and replace strings in its output.